# Hilbert space - probability measure: st. norm. variables

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, random-variables

I am considering the following homework.

> Let $\Omega=\ell_2$ be the Hilbert space of square summable sequences, $\mathcal A$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\{e_n: n\mbox{ natural}\}$ the natural basis. Then the  linear functionals $X_n(w)=\langle e_n,w\rangle$ are measurable on $\Omega$.

Is there $\mathbb P$ probability measure on $\mathcal A$, with $\mathbb P$ the $X_n$ will be i.i.d.?
Sorry for my English and thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X_n(\omega)\to 0$ poinwise, there would be convergence to $0$ in $\mathbb P$-probability, hence we cannot expect the $X_n$ to be identically distributed (unless we take $\mathbb P$ the Dirac mass at the origin).

But by Kolmogorov extension theorem, we can construct them in order to be independent.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's true.